# How to ignore file by name in all directories with pylint?

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I'd like pylint to ignore all my **init**.py files.
These files exist in all my directories and sometimes also in nested (on several levels) directories.

I have a .pylintrc file.
I tried to set the ignore-patterns options but it does not work.
I tried to do as follow:
ignore-patterns=^\w+/__init__.py
but however, it is not working and it would not work for nested files.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT

---

I set my ignore_patterns like this: **ignore-patterns=apps.py,__init__.py**

if I have a structure like this:

```
app 
  __init__.py  
  models
    __init__.py
```

the file inside models is ignored but not the one inside the app folder...

Is there anyway to do this ?

thanks

Comment: Try to use `^\w+/*__init__.py` instead.